# How can I create controls in a non main-thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

In our application we have the ability to print reports. For these reports we use Classes like FlowDocument, Canvas and some other controls like Labels. Since controls should only be created in the main-thread the applications shows a notification window and the user has to wait. A report can have up to 100 pages so this can take some minutes. And the user is unable to do anything else with the application.

Is there anyway to get out of this situation?

As I found out the problem is not exactly creating the document in a new thread. I can do this. But I am unable to show the document afterwards because it was not created by the main-thread. If I create it in the main-thread - this is what I do - it works fine.  But then the application is blocked while the report is generated.

Is there any way to transfer ownership of an object to another thread? Especially with UI-Elements like a Canvas? Like I say before I am able to create the report in an additional thread but the application refuses to display it. Controls not created/owned by the main-thread can not be shown.

Comment: Dealing with documents of that size demands a better solution than an out-of-box basic component.  This calls for a custom solution.  Without seeing your code it is difficult to suggest anything...

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Any UI control has to be managed by the `Dispatcher`

If you absolutely need to create controls from another thread, you need to invoke their creation/adding through the main Dispatcher, sync or async depending on your choices

Quick example for async call (change `BeginInvoke` to `Invoke` for sync, and play with the `DispatcherPriority` accordingly)

```
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                // Your control creation here
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

I used to work on a similar problem: Global `DockManager`, dynamic handling of docked content, I had to create my controls from the Dispatcher to be able to actually add them to my `DockManager`. Make sure you avoid any race condition with these calls and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to create a new thread with a dispatcher on it. In this separate thread, you can create the tree of elements and show it in a separate window that is independent of your main window's UI thread. Then the user can choose to print or not.

To create a new thread with a WPF dispatcher initialized on it, you can use the following code:

```
public class DispatcherBuilder : IBuilder<Dispatcher>
{
    public Dispatcher Build()
    {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = null;
        var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                var synchronizationContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(dispatcher);
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(synchronizationContext);

                manualResetEvent.Set();
                Dispatcher.Run();
            });
        thread.Start();
        manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
        manualResetEvent.Dispose();
        return dispatcher;
    }
}
```